# Getting 443 response from huggingface when trying to connect from Google Composer

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, huggingface-transformers, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to run gpt2 in Google CLoud Composer, but i'm getting error on requesting previous trained model with this message:

```
{connectionpool.py:1003} DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): huggingface.co:443
{connectionpool.py:456} DEBUG - https://huggingface.co:443
```

This is my code:

```
def _write_article_gpt2_test():
    generator = pipeline('text-generation', model='gpt2')
    set_seed(random.randint(1, 100))
    introduction = generator(
        "iphone is ", max_length=500, num_return_sequences=5)
    return introduction
```

How can I solve this?

This is the full log

```
[2022-12-30, 22:24:50 UTC] {connectionpool.py:1003} DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): huggingface.co:443
[2022-12-30, 22:24:51 UTC] {connectionpool.py:456} DEBUG - https://huggingface.co:443 "HEAD /gpt2/resolve/main/config.json HTTP/1.1" 200 0
[2022-12-30, 22:24:55 UTC] {taskinstance.py:872} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: dag_xxx.task_build_article_test manual__2022-12-30T22:24:36.796753+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2022-12-30, 22:24:56 UTC] {base_job.py:226} DEBUG - [heartbeat]
[2022-12-30, 22:25:01 UTC] {taskinstance.py:872} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: dag_xxx.task_build_article_test manual__2022-12-30T22:24:36.796753+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2022-12-30, 22:25:01 UTC] {base_job.py:226} DEBUG - [heartbeat]
[2022-12-30, 22:25:07 UTC] {taskinstance.py:872} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: dag_xxx.task_build_article_test manual__2022-12-30T22:24:36.796753+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2022-12-30, 22:25:07 UTC] {base_job.py:226} DEBUG - [heartbeat]
[2022-12-30, 22:25:12 UTC] {taskinstance.py:872} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: dag_xxx.task_build_article_test manual__2022-12-30T22:24:36.796753+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2022-12-30, 22:25:12 UTC] {base_job.py:226} DEBUG - [heartbeat]
[2022-12-30, 22:25:15 UTC] {local_task_job.py:156} INFO - Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGKILL
```

Comment: Are you sure 443 is an error?  Its awfully strange that 443 is also the default port number for HTTPS traffic.  In fact, the string "https://huggingface.co:443" doesn't look like an error at all but looks like a perfectly normal URL to me.

Comment: @Kolban I added the full log that return in error on the task. I run the same dag in my local Airflow and it works fine